# Honeypot Blade Form Input Field Issue

Tags: php, html, forms, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire

I'm having an issue with my blade form that implements honeypot. The issue I'm facing is that when I try and type into the first name input field, i can only type one character and the input is then deselected and I need to click again to then only type one other character. This issue is dependent on whether I position the honeypot element. If i place it directly underneath the "form" element, any input field i type into has the issue previously described. If i position it like the code example shown below, every other input field works other than the first name input field:

```
<form wire:submit.prevent="submit" class="px-6 pb-24 pt-20 sm:pb-32 lg:py-48 lg:px-8">
    <div class="mx-auto max-w-xl lg:mr-0 lg:max-w-lg">
        <div class="grid grid-cols-1 gap-y-6 gap-x-8 sm:grid-cols-2">
            <div>
                <x-honeypot livewire-model="extraFields" />
                <label for="first_name" :class="{'text-white': darkMode, 'text-gray-900': !darkMode }" class="block text-sm font-semibold leading-6">
                    First name
                    <span class="text-red-500 text-xs italic">*</span>
                </label>
                <div class="mt-2.5">
                    <input wire:model="first_name" type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" autocomplete="first_name"
                           :class="{'text-white bg-white/5 ring-white/10': darkMode, 'text-gray-900 placeholder:text-gray-400': !darkMode }"
                           class="block w-full rounded-md border-0 py-2 px-3.5 shadow-sm ring-1 ring-gray-300 ring-inset focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-indigo-600 sm:text-sm sm:leading-6">
                </div>
                @error('first_name')
                    <span class="text-red-500 text-xs italic">{{ $message }}</span>
                @enderror
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="last_name" :class="{'text-white': darkMode, 'text-gray-900': !darkMode }" class="block text-sm font-semibold leading-6">
                    Last name
                    <span class="text-red-500 text-xs italic">*</span>
                </label>
                <div class="mt-2.5">
                    <input wire:model="last_name" type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" autocomplete="last_name"
                           :class="{'text-white bg-white/5 ring-white/10': darkMode, 'text-gray-900 placeholder:text-gray-400': !darkMode }"
                           class="block w-full rounded-md border-0 py-2 px-3.5 shadow-sm ring-1 ring-gray-300 ring-inset focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-indigo-600 sm:text-sm sm:leading-6">
                </div>
                @error('last_name')
                    <span class="text-red-500 text-xs italic">{{ $message }}</span>
                @enderror
            </div>
            <div class="sm:col-span-2">
                <label for="message" :class="{'text-white': darkMode, 'text-gray-900': !darkMode }" class="block text-sm font-semibold leading-6">
                    Message
                    <span class="text-red-500 text-xs italic">*</span>
                </label>
                <div class="mt-2.5">
                    <textarea wire:model="message" name="message" id="message" rows="4"
                              :class="{'text-white bg-white/5 ring-white/10': darkMode, 'text-gray-900 placeholder:text-gray-400': !darkMode }"
                              class="block w-full rounded-md border-0 py-2 px-3.5 shadow-sm ring-1 ring-gray-300 ring-inset focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-indigo-600 sm:text-sm sm:leading-6"></textarea>
                </div>
                @error('message')
                    <span class="text-red-500 text-xs italic">{{ $message }}</span>
                @enderror
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mt-8 flex justify-end">
            <button type="submit" class="rounded-md bg-indigo-600 px-3.5 py-2.5 text-center text-sm font-semibold text-white shadow-sm hover:bg-indigo-500 focus-visible:outline focus-visible:outline-2 focus-visible:outline-offset-2 focus-visible:outline-indigo-600">Send message</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

what could be causing this and how could I fix this to allow all input fields to work as expected?

Answer (score 0):

The fix for this in my scenario was to add the honeypot element at the bottom of the form, rather than the top.